# String value won't inputted

Tags: java, arrays, do-while, netbeans-8

I am still beginner on programming.

my string value wont inputted on array

if i input "y" after input all the a b c, then input the a b c the array just get the last

```
String a, b, c, d;
    int x = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        x++;
        int e = x - 1;
        array = new String[x][3];

        System.out.println("input a : ");
        a = in.nextLine();
        array[e][0] = a;
        System.out.println("input b : ");
        b = in.nextLine();
        array[e][1] = b;
        System.out.println("input c : ");
        c = in.nextLine();
        array[e][2] = c;
        System.out.println("Again ? (y/n)");
        d = in.nextLine();

    } while (d.equals("y"));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Output "+(i+1)+" : ");
        System.out.println("a :" + array[i][0]);
        System.out.println("b :" + array[i][1]);
        System.out.println("c :" + array[i][2]);
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Define array outside of the loop.

Comment: `array = new String[x][3];` <- this will create a completly new Array and override all your previous data. If you want to have an array that "dynamically grows" you have to copy the data from the old array into the new one after creation

Comment: @SanketMakani his array variable is defined outside of the do loop. Now if you mean that he should create the array outside of the loop he would have the problem to klnow in advance how big his array is supposed to be while currently it is meant to grow dynamically.

Comment: so if the array is outside the loop how do i make a new row for the array?

Comment: @Albanna As i said you would have to first create a new Array with the new size, then copy all data from your old array to your new one. Unless using arrays is an Requirement i would recommend checking out ArrayList, as this class handles the "growing" by itself in the background and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in `do-while` loop, You are assigning a new `String` array to `array` in each iteration. Therefore It will not store the previously entered values. So at last when you print it, You will get only last entered entries and previously entered entries will be `null` as new Defined array has all elements as `null` initially. 
So you need to define the array outside of the `do-while` loop.

```
array = new String[4][3]; //Define array here of any appropriate size

do {
    x++;
    int e = x - 1;

    System.out.println("input a : ");
    a = in.nextLine();
    array[e][0] = a;
    System.out.println("input b : ");
    b = in.nextLine();
    array[e][1] = b;
    System.out.println("input c : ");
    c = in.nextLine();
    array[e][2] = c;
    System.out.println("Again ? (y/n)");
    d = in.nextLine();

} while (d.equals("y"));
```

In case you don't know the total size of `Array`, you can use dynamic structure like `ArrayList<String>`. You can use `ArrayList of ArrayList` or just different `ArrayList` manually but If your total possible inputs are more then it is preferable to use `ArrayList of ArrayList`.

**Different ArrayLists:**

This approach will help here If you know the total possible inputs. So here we know that we have total `3` possible inputs `a`,`b` and `c` So define `3` ArrayLists for each of `a`,`b` and `c`.

```
ArrayList<String> listA=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listB=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listC=new ArrayList<String>();

do {
    System.out.println("input a : ");
    a = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input b : ");
    b = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input c : ");
    c = in.nextLine();

    listA.add(a);
    listB.add(b);
    listC.add(c);

    System.out.println("Again ? (y/n)");
    d = in.nextLine();

} while (d.equals("y"));

for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println("Output "+(i+1)+" : ");
    System.out.println("a :" + listA.get(i));
    System.out.println("b :" + listB.get(i));
    System.out.println("c :" + listC.get(i));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: is there any ways if the array is not appropriate size?

Comment: He doesn't know how big his array needs to be until after the loop is finished. Thats the problem. You're code would quickly lead to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (if y is selected as the "again" option > 4 times).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Sorry about that but I updated the answer with other possible approaches.